# VPN for developement inside network

Tags: windows, networking, vpn

I have got a client who I am developing a program for which is only being used within their local network. The program connects to multiple internal IP addresses (databases and other devices), which are not accessible from outside of their network. The problem is that I need to be able to access these IP addresses from within another network (the place where I work). I cannot port forward anything due to their security protocols, so is there another way to set up a VPN or something?

Comment: Why do you need port forwarding if you are using Team Viewer?  The alternative to extensive port forwarding is indeed a VPN.  It is not clear what problem you want a solution to exactly.  You should edit and clarify your question.

Comment: @Ramhound I just changed the question, hope it's more clear now.